# Can Oath of Enmity and Divine Challenge be stacked on the same target?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, mark

We have a Paladin and an Avenger. Both aim to kill the last standing baddie. The Paladin uses Divine Challenge on the target, then the Avenger wishes to use Oath of Enmity on their next turn.

The Divine Challenge says only one mark can apply to a creature, therefore: does oath of emnity count as a mark?

Comment: Clarification: Oath of Enmnity is not a Mark and never Marks the target. "Mark" is a glossary term and should only be used when a power explicit states "Marks the target", not to refer to things tracked with tokens or markers. Even if Wizards releases little tokens including one that says "Avenger Mark" do not let yourself be confused ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can have both effects apply to one enemy. Oath of Enmity does not mark the opponent.

The only spells that mark an opponent are those that explicitly say they do so. For instance, Divine Challenge explicitly states "You mark the target."

If it clears things up: marking is a **condition**, just like *dazed*, *slowed* and *blinded* are - not a kind of power. Divine Challenge isn't "a mark", it **applies a mark** the same way an ice spell might apply the *slowed* condition or a psychic attack might apply the *blinded* condition. Because of this, a power doesn't  mark the target unless it says "the target is marked" - the same way that ice spell would say "the target is slowed". Some powers, like Divine Challenge, attach a bit extra to that marked condition, but it's still a condition.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. While the GM called the same as your answer eventually, we were still curious.